# How to multiply an array from a file to columns from another file and the sum?

Tags: bash, awk

I have an array of n species (s1 to sn) which stored as a column in file1. In the other hand, I have file2 with n columns with a length of m. I need to multiply the value of each value in file1 to multiply each columns of file2 and then sum each row and added in the last column of file2. As an example:

file1:

```
s1 1
s2 2
s3 3
s4 4
```

and file2:

```
s1 s2 s3 s4
10 20 30 40
11 21 31 41
12 22 32 42
13 23 33 43
```

and the result should be:

```
s1 s2 s3 s4 sum
10 20 30 40 10*1+20*2+30*3+40*4 
11 21 31 41 11*1+21*2+31*3+41*4
12 22 32 42 12*1+22*2+32*3+42*4
13 23 33 43 13*1+23*2+33*3+43*4
```

How can I do that with awk?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2; next} FNR>1{sum=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum += a[i] * $i; print sum}' file1 file2
```

but without some actual sample input and expected output it's hard to tell.